# Time characteristic in Stateful functions

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep, flink-statefun

I understand in general that event time uses Watermarks to make progress in time. In the case of Flink Statefun which is more based on iteration it may be a problem. So my question is if I use the delayed message (https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-statefun-docs-stable/docs/sdk/java/#sending-delayed-messages), then does it mean we can use only processing time notion in Stateful functions ?

I would like to change to Event time processing model but not sure how it will work with Stateful functions.

```
pipeline.time-characteristic: EventTime
pipeline.auto-watermark-interval: 200
```

Can someone explain if it is possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stateful Functions (statefun) doesn't support watermarks or event-time processing. But you could implement your own triggering logic based on the timestamps in arriving events.